# How do I mix an image with a specified color?

Tags: python, pygame, color, blending, fog

I have some images of static objects using per-pixel alpha (trees, rocks) for a background. In order to make them look a bit more natural, I want to create some kind of atmospheric fog, which means the farther away the object is, the more bluish tint it has.

I have the RGB color of a fog [108, 119, 135] (which appears to be a color of my image if it is totally far away) and I need to mix this color with my image somehow depending on the object's specified distance (which I'm mapping to percentage of fog).

If I had to mix solid colors, I'd just find the difference between the original color and 100% fog color, multiply this by the distance percentage, and subtract this from the original color. E.g. I have a value 208 in original red channel, and to make it 30% foggy I do `208-(208-108)*0.3 = 178`.

But I have no clue how to do this with an image that has per-pixel alpha. Blitting original image and then fog color with solid transparency doesn't work because I'd get a square of color over my image instead of respecting the shape of the image's alpha.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
import sys, pygame

def create_image_surface_with_fog(img,fog_color,fog_rate):
    _,_,w,h = img.get_rect()
    img_color = [(1-fog_rate) * 255] * 3
    fog_color = [x*fog_rate for x in fog_color]
    new_surface = pygame.Surface((w,h), pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
    new_surface.blit(img,img.get_rect())
    new_surface.fill(img_color,img.get_rect(),special_flags=pygame.BLEND_MULT)
    new_surface.fill(fog_color,img.get_rect(),special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGB_ADD)
    return new_surface

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

    character_img = pygame.image.load("character.png")
    background_img = pygame.image.load("background.png")

    fog_color = (108, 119, 135)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(background_img,background_img.get_rect())

        character_surface = create_image_surface_with_fog(character_img,fog_color,0.5)
        screen.blit(character_surface, (0, 0))

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Result when fog_rate= `0, 0.5, 1`:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Explain:

The smallest unit in which color blend occurs is the `pygame.Surface`. If you want it to respect the alpha of the original image, you need to draw the original image onto a separate surface. Then draw this surface to the screen surface:

```
def create_image_surface_with_fog(img,fog_color,fog_rate):
    new_surface = pygame.Surface((w,h), pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
    ...
    return new_surface
character_surface = create_image_surface_with_fog(character_img,fog_color,1)
screen.blit(character_surface, (0, 0))
```

For color mixing calculations, the calculation formula can be reorganized to reduce the number of drawings:

```
208-(208-108)*0.3 = (1-0.3)*208 + 0.3*108
```

So we only need to draw the original image once, `BLEND_MULT` once, and `BLEND_RGB_ADD` once:

```
new_surface.blit(img,img.get_rect())
new_surface.fill(img_color,img.get_rect(),special_flags=pygame.BLEND_MULT)
new_surface.fill(fog_color,img.get_rect(),special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGB_ADD)
```